# Script Timed Out When Generating a PDF document with REST API call

Tags: php, rest, api, pdf, request-timed-out

I am facing a problem when generating PDF document with REST API call using PHP. API returning more than 10k results but my script timed out and script can't generate the document. The REST API is for OpenSearchSever and I am using opensearchserver-php-client. For generating PDF I am using mPDF.

After some research, I find out some solution something like this

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1200M');
```

Is any better way to do this without script to timed out? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`1.2GB` to generate a `pdf` seems way to much, check if your code doesn't have any memory leaks.
Try to convert a very simple file, if it takes to much time, the problem may be related to the api.

---

The functions I use to keep a script running for as much time as it needs are:

`ignore_user_abort(1);`

> Set whether a client disconnect should abort script execution

`set_time_limit(0);`

> Limits the maximum execution time, in this case it runs until the
>   process finishes or webserver restarts.

Comment: I set 1.2GB for ensuring that it won't exceed that limit. thanks!